# Selecting items in a QTreeView with keyboard arrows

Tags: c++, qt, qtreeview

I'm trying to select an item in my QTreeView with the arrow keys but cannot find a method belonging to this class that returns the index of the highlighted item.
Up to now, i have only been able to select item with a click of the mouse :

```
connect(m_QTreeView, SIGNAL(clicked(QModelIndex)), this, SLOT(ItemTreeClicked(QModelIndex)));
```

but if I try to then change the focus with the keyboard arrows the current index is not updated.
To be honest, even my "mouse click" version isn't perfect because i have had use a Boolean that is initialized to false and passes to true when I enter the slot ItemTreeClicked. I had to do this because when i try to delete an item from the list, if I haven't clicked anything yet my app crashes.

I am coding in c++ on QtCreator 4.7.4

Any help or example code would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers.

Comment: You can handle selection changes in `QTreeView::selectionChanged()` virtual function, or using `QItemSelectionModel::selectionChanged()` signal of tree view's selection model.

Comment: At least in Qt5 this is the default behavior. The arrow keys move up/down and in/out of the tree. Of course only useful if you can use Qt5.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could subclass `QTreeView` and override the `keyPressEvent` method so it changes the [current index](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qabstractitemview.html#currentIndex)?

```
myqtreeview::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent* event){

    QModelIndex qmi = this->currentIndex();

    if(event->key() == Qt::Key_Down){
        this->setCurrentIndex(QAbstractItemModel::createIndex(qmi->row()+1, qmi->column()));
    }else{
        ...
    }
    QTreeView::keyPressEvent(event);
}
```

Note: This is just an idea, I can't test it at the moment so you probably have to adjust this a bit if you want to try it out